# How to find large files that are taking space in "Documents" category of Storage Manager

Tags: macos, finder, memory, storage

I am having trouble alleviating space problems on my Mac.
[image]

It states that I have over 330 GB worth of Documents. However, I've emptied and trash and cleaned up all large files:

[image]

I have no idea what files that are under "Documents" according to Storage Manager is taking up so much storage. Where can I look to find these hidden files that are taking up so much space on my Mac?

EDIT: I also know some cmd line / terminal. I tried running  `du -sh` on my /User/Peabrain directory and still have not gotten to a root cause for such the large storage

It does confirm however that the storage consumption is within my User space, as the cmd prints out at the end.
`342G   .`